# Как собрать проект NDK через консоль?

Tags: android-sdk, android-ndk

Есть готовый проект сделанный на **Android NDK**, и как мне теперь его **собрать через консоль**? Платформа ***Windows***
( я новенький в этой теме, пожалуйста разложите ответ полностью, прям можно по пунктам :) )

Answer (score 1):

В каталоге где лежат исходники создаем 2 файла

1. `Android.mk` - содержит список файлов для сборки и флаги компилятора - [подробнее здесь](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/android_mk)
2. `Application.mk` - релиз/дебаг версия и какие ABI (платформы собирать) - [подробнее здесь](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/application_mk)

Далее из этого каталога запускаем батник `ndk-build.cmd`, который валяется в корневом каталоге дистрибутива NDK (что то типа: `android-ndk-r10e`)

Кстати, все [описано в документации](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/build)